# For which conditions on countable sets does continuity implies uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

This is an exercise from Thomson and Bruckner's "Elementary Real Analysis" (Exercise 5.6.5 page 239):

> Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots\}$. What property must $X$ have so that every function continuous on $X$ is uniformly continuous on $X$?

The set $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb {R}$. I worked on the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definitions of limits and uniform continuity, but I coudln't link between them. Could you please help me?

**Edit**: I removed the part **My attempt** because my result was wrong.

Comment: As you know there are functions that are continuous in an interval, say $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R$, but not uniformly continuous - for example they may go to infinity at $a$ or $b$. But if the interval is closed, then the function is necessarily uniformly continuous. So my guess is that your set $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,,\}$ contains its $\inf$ and $\sup$ and also as you said $X\subset X'$

Comment: So I think the set $X$ should be of the form $[a,b]\cap \mathbb Q$, where $a,b \in\mathbb Q$ and $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Svetoslav that won't work. Consider $f(x) = 0$ for $x < c$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x > c$ for some $c\in[a,b]\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Comment: # user251257 I do not understant what you mean with the counterexample.

Comment: @Svetoslav: the function I gave is continuous on $X = [a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$ but not uniformly continuous on $X$.

Comment: Aha, you are right, @user251257 ! Thanks for the example.

Comment: @user251257 Indeed $f$ is continuous and not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Svetoslav I thinked about what if $\inf$ and $\sup$ are in $X$ and even what if $X$ is closed (and so $X=X'$) but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you for your answer. You're idea is so good I started trying to solve the problem, but then I remembered that $X\subset X'$ which is a necessary condition for the continuity to hold, whereas $\exists\varepsilon >0,\,\forall x,y\in X,\,|x-y|\ge\varepsilon$ contradicts this condition. In fact, I have the feeling that your idea is true if $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is a set on which $f$ is continuous, but the question is about a function defined on $X$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subset $X\subseteq \mathbb R$ has the property that every continuous $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is also uniformly continuous if and only if

> 1. $X$ is closed.
> 2. There exists some $M>0$ such that every limit point $p$ of $X$ follows $|p| < M$.
> 3. $X\setminus[-M, M]$ is uniformly discrete. That is, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x,y\in X\setminus[-M,M]$ with $x\ne y$ it follows
>      $$ |x-y| \ge \delta. $$

**If part:**

Since $X\cap[-M,M]$ is compact, any continuous function restricted onto $X\cap[-M,M]$ is uniformly continuous. Further, since $X\setminus[-M,M]$ is uniformly discrete, any function restricted onto $X\setminus[-M,M]$ is uniformly continuous.

**Only if part:**

1. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$, then we may extend $f$ to an uniformly continuous function on the closure of $X$. So, $\lim_{x\to x^*} f(x)$ need to exists for any closure point $x^*$ of $X$. Assume the contrary that $x^*$ is a limit point of $X$ not in $X$. Then, the function $f(x) = (x-x^*)^{-1}$ is continuous on $X$ but has no limit at $x^*$.
2. Assume the contrary that the limit points are unbounded, without the loss of generality unbounded from above. 
   Then, there exists a strictly increasing and unbounded sequence of limit points $p_0 < p_1 < \dotsb$. 
   Now, for $n\ge 1$ let 
   $$ \delta_n = \min\left\{\frac1n, \frac{p_{n} - p_{n-1}}{2}, \frac{p_{n+1} - p_{n}}{2} \right\}. $$
   Since $p_n$ is a limit point, there exists some $x_n\in X\setminus\{p_n\}$ with $\delta'_n := |x_n - p_n| < \delta_n$.
   Now, define the function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ by
   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & |x - p_n| < \delta'_n \text{ for some } n\ge 1, \\
   0, & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{cases}
   $$ 
   Then, $f$ is continuous, but $|f(x_n) - f(p_n)| = 1$ and $|x_n - p_n| < \frac1n \to 0$. That is, $f$ is not uniformly continuous.
3. Notice that $X\setminus[-M, M]$ is discrete. Assume that again the contrary that $X\setminus[-M, M]$ is not uniformly discrete. 
   Let $X_1 = X\setminus[-M, M]$.
   Let $x_1,y_1\in X_1$ with $x_1\ne y_1$ and $|x_1 - y_1| < 1$.
   Let $X_2 = X_1\setminus\{x_1, y_2\}$.
   Since $X_1$ is discrete, $X_2$ is discrete and therefore also closed. 
   Thus, $x_1$ and $y_1$ has positive distance to $X_2$, and $X_2$ is not uniformly discrete (otherwise $X_1$ would be also uniformly discrete, a contradiction).
   So, we can iteratively define $x_n,y_n\in X_n$ with $x_n\ne y_n$ and $|x_n-y_n| < \frac1n$ and $X_{n+1} = X_n\setminus\{x_n, y_n\}$.
   Define the function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ by
   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x = x_n \text{ for some } n, \\
   0, & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{cases}
   $$ 
   Then, $f$ is continuous. But $f(x_n) - f(y_n) = 1$ and $|x_n - y_n| < \frac1n \to 0$. Again, $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

**Notes:** Since the proof of 2. and 3. are similar, it might be possible to combine conditions 2 and 3 to something more nice looking.

Comment: So the sufficient condition that $X\cap [-M,M]$ is compact excludes the case when $X$ is dense in $[-M,M]$

Comment: Looks like $X$ has the property iff $X$ is closed and $X\setminus [-M,M]$ is uniformly discrete for some $M > 0.$ (The countability of $X$ doesn't really play a role.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We already established that $X\subset\mathcal{L}$ and $X$ is closed means $\mathcal{L}\subset X$. Thus $X=\mathcal{L}$ and so $X$ needs to be bounded too. Therefore $X$ must be compact. I still have to work on the sufficient condition now.

Comment: @Scientifica no, $X$ need not to be bounded

Comment: So saying that $X\subset\mathcal{L} $ is a mistake, but why?

Comment: @Scientifica notice for example that on $\mathbb N$ **any** function is uniformly continuous!

Comment: @Scientifica take $X=\{ 1/n \mid n\in \mathbb N\}$

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but there's definitively something that is out of my reach. For $\mathbb{N}$ and $X=\{\frac{1}{n}\, :\, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ no function is continuous (but yet uniform continuity is satisfied). Also, if $X$ needs not to be bounded, then why am I getting the following contradiction: $X\subset\mathcal{L}$ as I showed in my question ($\mathcal{L}=X'$). Since $\mathcal{L}$ is bounded, $X$ is also bounded because $X\subset\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: @Scientifica: just write down the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. you will notice that any function on a discrete space is continuous and any function on an uniformly discrete space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Scientifica As for $X=\{0\} \cup \{ 1/n \mid n\in\mathbb N \}$ (sorry forgot $0$). the only limit point is $0$. so $\mathcal L$ is always a subset of $X$ (by closeness). Not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you you're right: I shouldn't require $X\subset X'$ because a function can be continuous at an isolated point. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I'm now going to attempt a proof.

Comment: @Scientifica no need for sorry. you don't need to require $X\subset X'$. that is always true. notice there is a difference between limit point and closure  point

Comment: Thank you. Seems that there's a problem related to the definition of an accumulation point. In "Elementary Real Analysis", the definition is just the same as limit point, so $X'$ is just the same as $\mathcal{L}$. What is always true is $X\subset\bar{X}$ where $\bar{X}=X\cup X'$ is the set of boundary points of $X$. So whenever I used the term "accumulation point", I meant by it "limit point". I didn't know there was such a confusion.

Comment: @Scientifica oh it is my error. I read $X'$ as closure of $X$.

Comment: It is not necessary that $X \backslash[-M,M]$  be uniformly discrete for some positive  $M$. For example $ X=\{\log (n+1) : n \in N\}.$

Comment: It should be necessary and sufficient that  $X$ is closed and that $X\backslash (-M,M) $ is discrete for some $ M>0$.

Comment: @user254665 the indicator of $\{ \log(2n+1) \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous on your $X$

Comment: @Scientifica: I updated and corrected my answer. Just for the case if you stuck somewhere. The counter example with $x^2$ was wonky.

Comment: Your counterexample for part 3 is not well-defined. How do you know that $y_n$ is not equal to $x_m$ for some $m \neq n$, in which case $f(x_n) - f(y_n) = 0$?

Comment: @Bungo: right. I need to iteratively remove $x_n$ and $y_n$. I will fix it.

Comment: +1 Looks good now. I like the example of the indicator function of $\{\log(2n+1) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. This shows why it's not sufficient for all of the points of $X \setminus [-M,M]$ to be isolated: we might have a "limit point at $\infty$" if we don't enforce some minimum spacing between points.

Comment: @Bungo: Well, still ugly. I got the feeling there must be some more nice looking conditions which combine 2. and 3.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer! Indeed I was stuck: spent time trying to prove 2. and link 2. and 3. using te countability of $X$ but I failed to (sincerely I won't be able to think about one like yours). Unlike what @zhw said, countability of $X$ was used to denote the limit points as you did, since $X'$ is itself countable because $X'\subset X$. Excuse me, but I have a question about the function $f$ in 2: it seems to me that $f$ isn't well defined and that's because $\delta_n'$ wasn't chosen in a "unique" way:...

Comment: ... since $p_n\in X'$, we have $\exists y_n,z\in X\backslash\{p_n\},\,\gamma_n'=|y_n-p_n|<\delta_n'\land|y_n-p_n|<|z-p_n|<|x_n-p_n|$. So if one wants to calculate $f(z)$, it may be $1$ because $|z-p_n|<\delta_n'$ and it may be $0$ as well because $\gamma_n'<|z-p_n|$ (as if someone choosed the $y_n$ in your proof instead of $x_n$). But if we take $\delta_n'=\sup\{|x-p_n|\,:\,x\in X\backslash\{p_n\}\land|x-p_n|<\delta_n\}$, I believe we won't have any issue. We can choose $x_n$ to be any element of $\{x\in X\backslash\{p_n\}\,:\,|x-p_n|<\delta_n'\,\}$ since this set is nonempty ($\delta_n'>0$).

Comment: Nevertheless, your answer is great!

Comment: @Scientifica The set of limits points needs not to be countable. They could be uncountable. I just need a sequence of limit points which are unbound. I will correct it and make it more clear. Also, $\delta_n'$ needs not to be unique. I don't get your comment :( I construct $f$ such that it is constant $1$ in the $\delta_n'$ of $p_n$ and zero else where.

Comment: Ok I got it for 1. For 2 I didn't mean that $\delta_n'$ should be unique (in fact it isn't unique since $p_n$ is a limit point), but I proposed a way that makes it "unique", but you're right: defining it as you did makes the function well defined and causes no problem.

Comment: By the way, in 2., don't we have $f(x_n)-f(p_n)=-1$? Because $|p_n-p_n|=0<\delta'_n$ so $f(p_n)=1$ and $f(x_n)=0$ because the way $\delta_n$ is chosen we have $\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\,|x_n-p_m|\ge\delta_n'$. Even for $n$ we don't have $|x_n-p_n|<\delta_n'$ because it leads to $\delta_n'<\delta_n'$.

Comment: @Scientifica: oh right. I will fixed it. However, it won't break anything.

Comment: Yes of course! :D

Answer (score 4):

Partial results:

1. $X$ must be closed in $\mathbb {R}.$ If not, there is a sequence $x_n$ in $X$ with $x_n\to a, a\not \in X.$ Then the function $f(x) = 1/|x-a|$ is continuous on $X.$ The $x_n$ are getting close to one another, yet $f(x_n)$ is unbounded. Hence $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $X.$
2. Note that every function on $\mathbb N$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb N.$ So $X$ need not be bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $X$ closed then $X'\subset X$ but we also have $X\subset X'$ so $X=X'$. But your example in 2 doesn't seem good for me because no function on $\mathbb{N}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No, we don't have $X\subset X'.$ For the case of $\mathbb N,$ it is the opposite of what you say. Every function on $\mathbb N$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb N.$

Comment: I thought a point must be an accumulation point of the domain of $f$ to define continuity, but seems we can also define continuity at isolated points. Sorry for bothering you!