# What about the reciprocal of Heine theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

$i.e.$ What are the subsets $H$ $\subset$ $\mathbb R$ such that all continuous function $f$ $:$ $H$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous ?

Compact sets of course, but think about $\mathbb Z$ or more complicated subset.

Comment: If $H = \mathbb{Z}$ how do you propose to define a continuous function $f:H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? There are many ways to do this.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find all that satisfactory of an answer here because there is a pretty decent variety of weird subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ available, especially as you venture out into things which aren't open or closed.

Comment: I think all such functions are continuous/uniformly continious since there are (absolute) limits everywhere.

Comment: @Ian If $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ isn't closed, there are continuous functions $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ that aren't uniformly continuous. Consider $f(t) = \dfrac{1}{t - c}$ where $c\in \overline{A}\setminus A$. So we're only looking at closed subspaces, which removes much possible weirdness.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426874/251257 and my answer there

Comment: @user251257 Interesting, so roughly speaking all the noncompact examples are $\mathbb{Z}$ union a compact...

Comment: @Ian not necessarily $\mathbb Z$ but some uniformly discrete set.

Comment: @user251257 Sure, but that's what I mean by "roughly speaking". An unbounded uniformly discrete subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Ian yes, roughly. Just don't argue with topology in uniform context :D